# How can I see all ignored tests in Sonar?

Tags: java, testing, report, sonarqube

I have several ignored tests in tested code and I would like to investigate all of them. Is Sonar able to show such report?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can import your unit test execution report. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project#CodeCoveragebyUnitTestsforJavaProject-ReusingExistingReports for Java for example.